# Set DisplayMember and ValueMember on ComboBox without DataSource

Tags: .net, vb.net, combobox

I would like to have a `DisplayMember` and a `ValueMember` on a `ComboBox` which has only 4 values and they are always the same.

Is it possible without using a `DataTable` as `DataSource`and without creating a class?

I would like to have something like:

```
ValueMember= "Fixed"  
DisplayMember= "Specific and unique number"

ValueMember= "Multiple"  
DisplayMember= "Multiple and different numbers"

ValueMember= "Repeated"  
DisplayMember= "One number repeated x times"
```

Comment: Those are used to map the Properties of an object.  If yours has "values" there is nothing to map.  What exactly is in it?

Comment: @Plutonix I need values (string) but I want to show another string with explanation

Comment: Still not clear, but maybe you could use the format event

Comment: @Plutonix I edited my question. Hope it's clear now

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Fundamentally, you cant do what you want:

```
ValueMember= "Fixed"  
DisplayMember= "Specific and unique number"
```

`Value-` and `DisplayMember` are not for specifying the literal values, but are used to indicate the ***Property Names*** in something else (like a class).

---

Without using a `DataSource` (title) is not the same as not using a class (question text).  There are alternatives to creating a class:

#### Existing NET Types

You could use the existing NET `KeyValuePair` class to link a value with a name:

```
cbox.Items.Add(New KeyValuePair(Of String, String)("Specific", 
         "Specific and unique number"))
cbox.Items.Add(New KeyValuePair(Of String, String)("Multiple", 
         "Multiple and different numbers"))
cbox.Items.Add(New KeyValuePair(Of String, String)("Repeated", 
         "One number repeated x times"))

cbox.ValueMember = "Key"
cbox.DisplayMember = "Value"
```

There is no DataSource - the data is in the items collection.  There is also `Tuple` as explained in another answer

---

#### Anonymous Type

Using one string as the key for another string is a quite odd.  Typically in code you would want something less prone to errors from typos.  Typing "Fized" somewhere breaks your code.  An `Enum` makes much more sense:

```
Private Enum ValueStyle
    Specific = 0
    Multiple = 1
    Repeated = 2
End Enum
```

Now, you can create a `List` which links a description for the user and the `Enum` constants:

```
' fuller text descr of the enum for the user
Dim descr As String() = {"Specific and unique number",
                         "Multiple and different numbers",
                         "One number repeated x times"}
' get enum values into an array of ValueStyle
Dim values = [Enum].GetValues(GetType(ValueStyle)).Cast(Of ValueStyle).ToArray

' create a List of anon objects from the descr() and values()
Dim lst = values.Select( Function (q) New With
                       {.Value = q, .Name = descr (q)}
                    ).ToList()
    
cboPicker.ValueMember = "Value"
cboPicker.DisplayMember = "Name"
cboPicker.DataSource = lst
```

This creates an *Anonymous Type* - an object without a class - with a Name and Value property mapped to the Enum and description array.  If the `Enum` values are not sequential (e.g. {8, 65, 99}), the list would have to be built differently.

This creates a temporary collection of *Anonymous Type* objects and assigns it as the DataSource.  You wont be able to access the `Name` and `Value` properties in other methods because anonymous type cant be passed to other methods.  But the user will see the desired text and NET/VB will provide the value as that enum as the `SelectedValue`.  Using the `SelectedValue` changed event:

```
' name user sees == cboPicker.Text
' value == cboPicker.SelectedValue boxed as Object

Dim userChoice As ValueStyle = CType(cboPicker.SelectedValue, ValueStyle)
If userChoice = ValueStyle.Specific Then
    '...
ElseIf userChoice = ValueStyle.Repeated Then
    '...
End If
```

Notice that rather than testing "Fixed" as a string, the code uses the enum but is still every bit as readable.

MSDN: **[Anonymous Types (Visual Basic)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384767.aspx)**

---

Those fit the criteria of not needing a new class, but consider:

```
Friend Class NameValuePair
    Public Property Name As String
    Public Property Value As Int32

    Public Sub New(n As String, v As Int32)
        Name = n
        Value = v
    End Sub

    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        Return Name
    End Function

End Class
```

The class is very simple and is almost infinitely reusable in associating any `Name` with any `Value`.  It could be used with any number of list based controls, in any number of projects.  The code to create and use a list of them is simpler than using the other methods.

Comment: Very thanks for detailed answer. I'll study it (I'm still not able to understand all you showed)

Answer (score 3):

Using some class is a solution, but because you don't want use custom class - use build-in type.

```vb
Dim values As New List(Of Tuple(Of String, String))()
values.Add(New Tuple("Fixed", "Specific and unique number"))
values.Add(New Tuple("Multiple", "Multiple and different numbers"))
values.Add(New Tuple("Repeated", "One number repeated x times"))
'and so on...

combobox.ValueMember = "Item1"
combobox.DisplayMember = "Item2"
combobox.DataSource = values
```

[Tuple(Of T1, T2) Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd268536(v=vs.110).aspx)

But for sake of readability my advise use custom class.
Or just in case of reusing custom class is better than `Tuple`

Answer (score 0):

cbActive is a combobox

```
Private Sub LoadActiveCB()

    Dim _Active As New List(Of ActiveCB)

    _Active.Add(New ActiveCB With {.Name = "Fixed", .ID = 1})
    _Active.Add(New ActiveCB With {.Name = "Multiple", .ID = 2})
    _Active.Add(New ActiveCB With {.Name = "Repeated", .ID = 3})

    cbActive.DataSource = _Active
    cbActive.DisplayMember = "Name"
    cbActive.ValueMember = "ID"

End Sub

Class ActiveCB
    Property Name As String
    Property ID As Byte
End Class
```

You'll have to tweak it a bit, change the display and value members, but I believe this may be what you want...?

Comment: What is `ActiveCB`? I don't want to use a custom class.

Comment: @genespos just remove it and it will be an anonymous type.  You could also bootstrap it from a decorated enum

Comment: Oh, sorry I forgot that... My bad. I don't understand your application of this when it would just be something like

` Class ActiveCB
 Property Name As String
 Property ID As Byte
End Class  '

Comment: @Plutonix I didn't understand what you mean: how can I use this code without setting a new class?

Answer (score 0):

I think I get it now... Maybe something like:

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim comboSource As New Dictionary(Of String, String)()
        comboSource.Add("1", "Sunday")
        comboSource.Add("2", "Monday")
        comboSource.Add("3", "Tuesday")
        comboSource.Add("4", "Wednesday")
        comboSource.Add("5", "Thursday")
        comboSource.Add("6", "Friday")
        comboSource.Add("7", "Saturday")
        ComboBox1.DataSource = New BindingSource(comboSource, Nothing)
        ComboBox1.DisplayMember = "Value"
        ComboBox1.ValueMember = "Key"
    End Sub
    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim key As String = DirectCast(ComboBox1.SelectedItem, KeyValuePair(Of String, String)).Key
        Dim value As String = DirectCast(ComboBox1.SelectedItem, KeyValuePair(Of String, String)).Value
        MessageBox.Show(key & "   " & value)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Credit: http://net-informations.com/q/faq/combovalue.html

Answer (score 0):

Given a IList of anonymous types pointing to a database entities in VB, I use it to build an anonymous list with one member pointing to the db entity object (PO) and another to a composite of the values in the entity (Display):

```
Dim aList = _BO_Data.Lines
       .Select(Function(PO) ew With {.ACBond = PO, .Display = (PO.Product.Code_item & " - " & PO.Product.Descr)}).ToList()

Combobox_Code_Product.DataSource = aList
Combobox_Code_Product.DisplayMember = "Display"
Combobox_Code_Product.ValueMember = "ACBond"
```

Then the combobox SelectedItem is the ACBond object and the what I see in the list is the mix of the code and the description of the product.