# Combo Box Drop down list to change a variable

Tags: .net, vb.net, data-binding, combobox

I am creating a program with a Drop Down-list combo Box which contain the items: `a`,`b`,`c`and `d`.

What I want to do is, when I select an item in the ComboBox and then click a button, the x variable will change. For example when I select `b` in the ComboBox, the x value will change to `2`.

I need this variable for another function. How can I change the `x` variable?

Comment: [Set DisplayMember and ValueMember on ComboBox](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38206678/1070452)

Comment: i have solved the problem, thank you for the response

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```vb
If ComboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString = "a" Then
    x = 1
ElseIf ComboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString = "b" Then
    x = 2
ElseIf ComboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString = "c" Then
    x = 3
ElseIf ComboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString = "d" Then
    x = 4
End If
```

Assuming x is an Integer

Comment: thank you , currently im using `ComboBox.SelectedIndex`  and it solve my problem, what the difference with `ComboBox1.SelectedItem` by the way?

Comment: @Yon - Selected index gets the position of the selected item. Ex. `0` (First) or `1` (Second) or `2` (Third) e.t.c. Selected item gets the text of the selected item (In your case: `a` or `b` or `c` or `d` e.t.c)

Comment: @Yon - Mark an answer so people know that you solved your problem.

Answer (score 2):

Or you could use a Select Case statement

```
Select Case ComboBox1.Text
    Case "a"
        x = 1 
    Case "b"
        x = 2
    Case "c"
        x = 3
    Case "d"
        x = 4
End Select
```

Comment: i have solved the problem, thank you for the response

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to bind a datasource to your combobox. That way if you decide to add a new value later or change how it works, this is all in one place:

```
    Dim dict As New Dictionary(Of String, Integer)
    dict.Add("a", 1)
    dict.Add("b", 2)
    dict.Add("c", 3)
    dict.Add("d", 4)
    ComboBox1.DisplayMember = "Key"
    ComboBox1.ValueMember = "Value"
    ComboBox1.DataSource = New BindingSource(dict, Nothing)
```

then in the SelectedValueChanged Event you can read the value of `x`:

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedValueChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedValueChanged
    If ComboBox1.SelectedValue IsNot Nothing Then x = CInt(ComboBox1.SelectedValue)
End Sub
```