# How to set SelectedValue for Enum bound ComboBox

Tags: .net, vb.net, combobox, enums

I have bound a ComboBox to an enum like so

```
Enum Foo
    Bar
    Baz
End Enum

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    FooComboBox.DataSource = [Enum].GetValues(GetType(Foo))
End Sub
```

I would like to change the selected value at a given time

```
Private Sub FooBar()
    FooComboBox.SelectedValue = Foo.Bar
End Sub
```

But this throws an exception:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll
>
> Additional information: Cannot set the SelectedValue in a ListControl with an empty ValueMember.

And inspecting the ComboBox I can indeed see that the `ValueMember` property is empty. But `SelectedValue` **is** equal to the value expected for the currently selected item when I read it, which would indicate that the `ValueMember` *is* set to the enum value as was expected.

A) If the `ValueMember` property is not set, where is the value in `SelectedValue` coming from?

B) If the binding is causing `SelectedValue` to contain the correct value, why the flip doesn't setting it work in just the same way?

C) What else do I need to do to make this bloody .Net work?

<sub>Note that there are indeed quite a few C# & WPF questions on this, none really explain this as far as I have seen  and I haven't been able to work out what the correct vb syntax would be from the answers suggested them.</sub>

Comment: I can use `SelectedIndex` to achieve the desired effect, *but* that's because, by coincidence, the index of the items match the enum values. What happens when the enum values are different to the index?

Comment: `FooComboBox.SelectedItem = Foo.Bar`  When they are not simple {0,1,2} values, use a Type to set both the Value and Displaymember

Comment: @Plutonix, how does one "use a Type to set the Value and DisplayMember"?

Comment: There is [Assigning a value to ComboBox Items](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31777645/1070452)  using Enum.Names and ENum.Values;  and also [Set DisplayMember and ValueMember on ComboBox without DataSource](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38206678/1070452) which makes it more complex than it needs to be with the "without datasource" requirement

Comment: Ah you mean use a collection of complex types and bind to that... Bit much for a simple short, constant, list of numbers, no? God I hate VB.

Comment: If the values are non sequential, its not all that simple - the control needs to know how to map the name to the value.  It is pretty easy to write a method to return a List of NameValuePairs for any Enum...even allowing for using Descriptions where available.

Comment: That sounds decent. Uses reflection to get names? Maybe you could add a short example as an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Particularly when the values are not sequential, you need to provide a way for the control to "map" the Name to the related value.  Once you post `Enum.GetValues` or the Names to a CBO, they have become detached.

You can use something like a `KeyValuesPair(of String, Int32)` using the names as TKey and the values as TValue.  The generic can make it seem more complex than it is.  Since the key will always be `String`, and the value is *usually* an `Int32` I tend to use a simple `NameValuePair` class for these:

```
Public Class NameValuePair
    Public Property Name As String
    Public Property Value As Int32

    Public Sub New(n As String, v As Int32)
        Name = n
        Value = v
    End Sub

    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        Return String.Format("{0}", Name)
    End Function
End Class
```

That will associate any name with any value. The main thing is that you control what displays for `ToString()`. In this case, both the name and value come from an Enum; a simple method to create a List or Array of them:

```
Private Enum Stooges
    Moe = 9
    Larry = 99
    Curly = 45
    Shemp = 65
    CurlyJoe = 8
End Enum

' method to convert any Enum to a collection of Named-Value pairs
Private Function EnumToPairsList(e As Type) As List(Of NameValuePair)
    Dim ret As New List(Of NameValuePair)

    Dim vals = [Enum].GetValues(e)
    Dim names = [Enum].GetNames(e).ToArray

    For n As Int32 = 0 To names.Count - 1
        ret.Add(New NameValuePair(names(n), CType(vals.GetValue(n), Int32)))
    Next

    Return ret
End Function
```

`EnumsToPairsList` could return an array, or use `KeyValuePair` as desired.  It can be expanded to use a `Description` in place of the name when present. Using it:

```
cbox1.DataSource = EnumToPairsList(GetType(Stooges))
cbox1.DisplayMember = "Name"   ' use "Key" for a KVP
cbox1.ValueMember = "Value"

' set a value:
cbox1.SelectedValue = Convert.ToInt32(Stooges.Shemp)
```

#### Using It

Since you have "wrapped" the enum in the NVP class, that is what each `SelectedItem` will be (enclosed in an `Object`).  When using a `DataSource` such as this, you would typically act in the `SelectedValueChanged` event and examine the `SelectedValue`.  This is the main purpose of it: show the names to the user, but return the enum value to you in code.

The only "trick" is that it needs to be cast back to your enum:

```
Private Sub cbox1_SelectedValueChanged(...
    Dim eItem As Stooges = CType(cbox1.SelectedValue, Stooges)
    Console.WriteLine(eItem)
    Console.WriteLine(eItem.ToString)
```

> 45
>     Curly

If you insist on using `SelectedItem`, you will have to cast from `Object` to `NameValuePair`, get the Value, then cast *that* to your Enum Type.

---

It is often useful to hold onto a copy of the data source so it resides somewhere other than only as a control datasource:

```
Private StoogesDS As List(Of NameValuePair)
...
StoogesDS = EnumsToPairsList(GetType(Stooges))
cbox1.DataSource = StoogesDS
```

This allows your code to still use the collection even when the form is not around.  As noted above, each item is now a `NameValuePair` object.

```
cbox1.SelectedItem = StoogesDS.FirstOrDefault(Function(z) z.Name = Stooges.Shemp.ToString())
```