# displaying data from a two dimensional array into a combobox and a textbox

Tags: arrays, vb.net, combobox

i have a two dimentional array for  items and prices in vb.net:

```
Dim items(,) As String = {{"Chicken Sand", "9000"}, {"Roast Beef Sand", "13500"}, 
                 {"Salmon Sand", "13500"}, {"Tuna Sand", "11000"},
                 {"Halloumi Sandwich", "7000"}, {"Ham & Cheese Sand", "8000"}, 
                 {"Water", "1500"}, {"Soft Drink", "2500"}, 
                 {"Fresh Lemonade", "3000"}, {"Fresh Orange", "3500"}}
```

I want to fill a combobox with items from this array 
and when each item from the combobox is selected I want that the price will be displayed in a textbox specific for the price.
I reached:

```
For row = 0 To items.GetUpperBound(0)
    cbitem.Items.Add(items(row, 0))
Next`
```

Comment: You can use a utility class or an Anonymous type to create a DataSource as the linked answers show

Comment: @Plutonix i didn't understand

Comment: If you want to display one thing to the user and collect something else like a value, you should use a datasource. It can be a datatable or list(of T) or a list of anonymous types.  The linked post shows how as does: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39024484/1070452  It will also let you store the price as a value rather than text

Comment: @Plutonix there is no way to use a two dimentional area ??

Comment: You arent really using a 2D array  -  you are iterating it to extract the data one by one anyway.  Might as well do it correctly

Comment: Those things have 2 properties: a name and a price stored as string.  Why store them seperately when they can be together and of the correct data type?

Comment: yes got it. but this is a homework and we were asked to fill the combobox with items by a two dimentional array. this is why i am asking you if it can work.

Comment: @Plutonix i forgot to tag you in the previous comment

Comment: You only need to ping (`@`+name) when more than one person has commented.  The items collection can hold anything but each can only store one thing - you want to store 2 things.  If you glue the elements together (`"Tuna Sand (11000)"`) you could parse it back out when they select, but it is a wet bag of hair compared to using a DataSource

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this is a homework and we were asked to fill the combobox with items by a two dimentional array`

This is not a good way to do this compared to using a datasource:

You cant actually put your array into the `ComboBox` because `Items` is a collection, not a multi-D array.  But you can use it as a look up for what was selected.  Be sure your array has form level scope:

```
Option Strict On
Public Class MenuFrm

    Private items(,) As String = {{"Chicken Sand", "9000"}, {"Roast Beef Sand", "13500"},
                    {"Salmon Sand", "13500"}, {"Tuna Sand", "11000"},
                    {"Halloumi Sandwich", "7000"}, {"Ham & Cheese Sand", "8000"},
                    {"Water", "1500"}, {"Soft Drink", "2500"},
                    {"Fresh Lemonade", "3000"}, {"Fresh Orange", "3500"}}
```

Later, perhaps in form load, fill the cbo with the names:

```
For row = 0 To items.GetUpperBound(0)
    cbox1.Items.Add(items(row, 0))
Next
```

Now, when they pick something look up the string price:

```
Private Sub cbox1_SelectedIndexChanged1(sender As Object, 
        e As EventArgs) Handles cbox1.SelectedIndexChanged
    If cbox1.SelectedIndex < 0 Then Return
    Dim price = Convert.ToDecimal(items(cbox1.SelectedIndex, 1))
End Sub
```

A proper `DataSource` would store the price as a numeric, keep the price with the menu item and make it all available in the `SelectedValueChanged`.

- **[Assigning a value to ComboBox Items](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31777645/1070452)**
- **[Set DisplayMember and ValueMember on ComboBox](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38207397/1070452)**
- **[How to set SelectedValue for Enum bound ComboBox](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39023109/1070452)**

Comment: thank you so much @plutonix i will use the 2d array since this is what was asked from me. And thank you for the DataSource way it is better.